# Stepping through a named range array

Tags: excel, vba

I know this is something simple that I am missing.  I am creating a function that will update my Pivot Tables and I am trying to code this so it will read the variables from a table in the Excel workbook.

To keep it simple this is what I would like to do.

I have a list of all my Pivot Tables and then next to the name I have a parameter so I know what else I need for my update.  So I need to be able to loop through my named table and get the first field which is the Pivot Table Name and then the field next to the name which is a parameter I will need for my code.

Here is what I have and I know it is not correct.

```
Sub myPivotTableNames()

Dim myPTNames

Dim myPTUpdateName
Dim myPTUpdateVariable

myPTNames = Range("DATA_PIVOT_TABLES").Columns(1)
myPTParameters = Range("DATA_PIVOT_TABLES").Columns(2)
    'Get the Pivot Table to update
    For Each myPTName In myPTNames
        myPTUpdateName = myPTName
        
        'Get the Parameters to update
        For Each myPTParameter In myPTParameters
            myPTUpdateParameter = myPTParameter
                MsgBox "Pivot Table:  " & myPTUpdateName & vbCrLf & "Pivot Parameter: " & myPTUpdateParameter
        Next myPTParameter

        Call UpdatePivotTable(myPTUpdateName, myPTUpdateParameter)

    Next myPTName
End Sub
```

I am getting the pivot table name but then it will loop through all the parameters and if I did not have the msgbox I would just get me last parameter in the list.

I see what I need to do I just am not sure how to do it.

Thanks,
Rodger

OK I made the updates to the code but now it will not loop

```
Sub myPivotTableNames()

    Dim myPTName As Range
    Dim myPTParameter As Range  
    Dim myPTNames As Range   
    Dim myPTUpdateName
    Dim myPTUpdateParameter
    Dim x As Integer

    x = 3  
    Set myPTNames = Range("DATA_PIVOT_TABLES").Columns(1)
  
    'Get the Pivot Table to update
    For Each myPTName In myPTNames
        
        myPTUpdateName = myPTName
            
        Set myPTParameter = myPTName.Offset(0, 1)
        myPTUpdateParameter = myPTParameter.Value
                    
        Cells(x, 5).Value = myPTUpdateName
        Cells(x, 6).Value = myPTUpdateParameter
        Cells(x, 7).Value = "Done"
        x = x + 1
    Next myPTName
End Sub
```

I am not sure why.

Here is the Updated Code.  It will work fine the first time and on the second time it is grabbing the sheet name and not the pivot table name.  It is like it is all be shifted to the right by one.

```
Sub myPivotTableNames()

Dim mySheets As String
Dim myPVTableStyle As String
Dim myResult

Dim myMonthValue As String
Dim myYearValue As String

Dim myPTName As Range
Dim myPTSheet As Range
Dim myPTParameter As Range

Dim myPTNames As Range

Dim myPTUpdateName As String
Dim myPTUpdateParameter
Dim myPTUpdateSheet As String

Dim x As Integer

x = 3
myPVTableStyle = Range("PT_DEFAULT_STYLE").Value

Application.StatusBar = True

Set myPTNames = Range("DATA_PIVOT_TABLES") '.Columns(1)

    'Get the Pivot Table to update
    For Each myPTName In myPTNames
Stop
        myPTUpdateName = myPTName
            If myPTUpdateName = myPTUpdateParameter Then GoTo NextName
            
            Set myPTSheet = myPTName.Offset(0, 1)
            Set myPTParameter = myPTName.Offset(0, 2)
        
                myPTUpdateSheet = myPTSheet.Value
                myPTUpdateParameter = myPTParameter.Value
                   
                'myPTUpdateParameter
                '1 = Current Month / Current Year
                If myPTUpdateParameter = 1 Then
                    myMonthValue = Range("PT_CURRENT_MONTH")
                    myYearValue = Range("PT_CURRENT_YEAR")
                End If
                '2 = YTD Month / YTD Year
                If myPTUpdateParameter = 2 Then
                    myMonthValue = Range("PT_YTD_MONTHS")
                    myYearValue = Range("PT_PRIOR_YEAR")
                End If
                '3 = Budget Month / Budget Year
                If myPTUpdateParameter = 3 Then
                    myMonthValue = Range("PT_BUDGET_MONTH")
                    myYearValue = Range("PT_BUDGET_YEAR")
                End If
                '4 = YTD Budget Months / YTD Budget Years
                If myPTUpdateParameter = 4 Then
                    myMonthValue = Range("PT_BUDGET_YTD_MONTHS")
                    myYearValue = Range("PT_BUDGET_PRIOR_YEAR")
                End If

                        Application.StatusBar = "Updating Pivot Table " & myPTUpdateName & " starting."
            
                            myResult = UpdatePivot(myPTUpdateSheet, myPTUpdateName, "Admit Year", myYearValue, myPVTableStyle)
                            myResult = UpdatePivot(myPTUpdateSheet, myPTUpdateName, "Admit Month", myMonthValue, myPVTableStyle)
                
                            Cells(x, 9).Value = Now()
                            
NextName:
    x = x + 1
    Next myPTName
End Sub
```

The Table has four (4) columns
1. PivotTable Name
2. Worksheet Name
3. Parameters
4. Update Date Time (This gets an update from the code.)

Comment: Is this `Call UpdatePivotTable(myPTUpdateName, myPTUpdateParameter)` supposed to be inside the `For Each` loop just before? Btw, you can write `UpdatePivotTable myPTUpdateName, myPTUpdateParameter` without the `CALL` and the `()`

Comment: Yes it need to come right before it the first loop as it has the pivot table name.  I was just putting the call so you would see that is what I need to build.

Comment: If  myPTName is a range then do you simply need to `myPTName.offset(0,1)` column to right to get parameter without need for loop over params?

Comment: I thought I tried to do an offset and I was getting an error.  I did a myPTParameter = myPTName.Offset(1) so do I change that to (0,1)?

Comment: to go one column to right and also declare `Dim myPTName As Range,  myPTParameter  As Range`.  Then later use `SET myPTParameter = myPTName.Offset(0,1)` And access its value with `myPTParameter.value`

Comment: OK I will try that.  This is for work and I just left.  I will try in the morning.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @QHarr - I made the changes as you suggested and thank you it is working better; however it is not looping now.  It's like it only see one row in my range.  I verified the "DATA_PIVIOT_TABLES" is B2:C22.  I updated my post with your code suggestions.

Comment: `For Each myPTName In myPTNames.Cells`  ?

Comment: Is that something I should try.  I did cheat and I added a if then goto statement.  It is working but now I am adding in another parameter I need to add in the sheet name as I have 4 different sheets.  The first pass is working but then on the next pass it seems to shift the data over a column.  I am going to work on it a bit more and come back if I need some help.  Thanks again!!

Comment: OK I am not sure how to do what I want.  It makes the first pass fine then when it loops back it is like the code is shifting the table to the right one.  I know I am doing an offset, but I was thinking I was starting from column 1 and then the offset moves it over 1 and then 2 so I can get the other parameters I need.  The updated Code is above.  Thank you again.